# Is there a way to create a broadcast stream with the async* syntax [Dart]

Tags: dart

Taking [this example](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#creating-a-stream-from-scratch) from the Dart docs. Is there a way to make `timedCounter()` return a broadcast stream by definition?

```dart
Stream<int> timedCounter(Duration interval, [int? maxCount]) async* {
  int i = 0;
  while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(interval);
    yield i++;
    if (i == maxCount) break;
  }
}
```

Not looking for `timedCounter().asBroadcastStream()` nor with using a `StreamController`.
This question is more about if the syntax of defining a function with `async*` limits the result stream to be a single subscription.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The `Stream` created by an `async*` function is always a single-subscription stream.
If you want a broadcast stream, either use `.asBroadcastStream()` or, preferably, use a broadcast stream controller directly.

An `async*` function is intended to execute normally until it's done, driven by the normal control flow of a single (asynchronous) function.

Broadcast streams are usually used for firing events in response to other things happening. While you can do something like that using an `async*` function, it's actually very easy to make mistakes (like not catching an error and that terminating the stream before you intend to).
So, at least for now, `async*` streams are single-subscription.
(If I could change that, I'd make them *multi-subscription* like the [`Stream.multi`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-async/Stream/Stream.multi.html) constructor, where each listen gets its own sequence of events starting from scratch, not a broadcast stream where listeners share the same events).